# How to debug a CHOOSER action in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I noticed that when I tap on a "Browse..." (or "Choose File") button in Firefox and in Chrome respectively, the system shows a different list of apps in its app chooser dialog popup window. I'm trying to find out what is the difference between the intent fired by both browsers that lead to this difference in behavior.

Using `adb logcat` while taping the file chooser button, I found this line.

> ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.CHOOSER cmp=android/com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity (has extras)} from uid 12345 on display 0

The issue I have is that it's the same line for both browsers (except the uid, of course).

How can I get additional details to find out what makes those intents different?

Comment: AFAIK the chooser is called with a MIME type you want to open - for example, if you request the chooser to select an app to open MIME type "pdf" it will list the apps that are "registered" as pdf readers. So probably it depends on the browser implementation.

Comment: Is there a way to introspect the MIME type the browser used?